# Which noSQL database to choose for a network daemon?

Tags: mongodb, cassandra, nosql

I am writing a custom server, which should be very performant.
It has 100.000-600.000 clients connected, and like 10 million records stored.
Database will run on a single server.

The server code is realized via twisted framework (in python).
Now I had it use MySQL, but I think a NoSQL database would be much more efficient (no complex queries, many simple writes / timestamp changes and many simple reads).

Which NoSQL database should I go for? Easy indexing would be a plus, I want the option to search the database from an administration system, create groups from logs containing a specific keyword and stuff like that.

I had a look at Cassandra and MongoDB, MongoDB seemed easier to get in / use for me.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as pure learning curve goes, MongoDB has positioned itself to be a very friendly alternative to MySQL.  Cassandra is a very different beast and will have a higher learning curve.  That said, both have the potential to solve your problem based upon what you describe.

Comment: Thank you, i will stick with MongoDB. It looks very comfortable.

Answer (score 1):

You have pretty simple requirements: easy indexing, arbitrary searches, grouping on keyword, etc -- pretty much every NoSQL system would work. It really comes down to the technologies with which you're comfortable. Like C#? Then go with RavenDB  -- it can even automatically add indices as you execute queries. Like Erlang? Then you're a freak, but you should go with CouchDB. Like Javascript and JSON? Go with MongoDB.

Personally I really like Mongo, as it feels like a  lovely hybrid of SQL and NoSQL databases. You can index the hell out of it (and get amazing performance!), which makes it almost like a RDBMS. You can also use it like a key/value store, and use it like a "giant hashtable in the sky". Still, YMMV. Play with them and see what works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra is really designed for multiple server nodes, providing transparent replication. So you won't get the best value out of it with a single server host. Cassandra is also designed primarily for large-scale (and sacrifices indexing and flexible queries as a result). 10 million records isn't really very big, so you can afford to try something more flexible but less scalable.